# Eclipse cannot find Android Support Library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I am an experienced programmer but new to Android, hence using Eclipse for the first time.
Unfortunately I cannot get my first project off the ground. I get as far trying to create the project when the following sequence happens.
A screen arrives titled 'Install Dependencies' telling me that the required version is 8 and the installed version is 'Not installed'
I click on the Install/Upgrade button and something must happen because Android SDK Manager pops up and I get a whole series of 'Fetching:' messages.
The next screen asks me to Choose Package to Install and the only option is Android Support Library, revision 10. This doesn't bother me as I presume 10 is better than 8 so I hit the Install button.
This is where it all goes wrong as I get a red message saying:-
File not found:C:\Program Files (X86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\support_r10.zip (Acces is denied).
Sure enough, when I check this folder, it is empty.

Now, something must have happened as as SDK Manager did a whole lot of fetching and must have put these files somewhere.

I am quite happy to find them and put them in the correct folder but the question is

What is the name of the files that I am looking for?

Answer (score 4):

Run SDK Manager as administrator and then install Android Support Library from Extras

Answer (score 0):

Download the sdk manager seperately and install files from there. put it in a place which is accessible to you and then point your eclipse android directory to it. tools>options>android sdk

Answer (score 0):

Run eclipse as Administrator. This is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your application (Eclipse) in Admin Mode.
Right click on the Eclipse app, and choose "Run as Administrator"
This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

properties >java build path >click library tab > add jars > add jars from the support library.